# Расчет возможных процессов gunicorn

Tags: flask, gunicorn

Как рассчитать сколько процессов (N) можно запустить с gunicorn учитывая многоядреность процессора?

`gunicorn -b localhost:8000 -w N project:app`

Так же если имеются какие-то статьи, прошу  накидать.

Answer (score 0):

В документации рекомендуют (2 x $количество_ядер) + 1. Избыточное количество воркеров может снизить производительность.

См. https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html#how-many-workers

Также есть интересное обсуждение относительно Амазоновских инстансов https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979428/what-is-the-appropriate-number-of-gunicorn-workers-for-each-amazon-instance-type